# syntax error at or near ";" LINE 22 - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am creating a user defined function in PostgreSQL and facing error.

Also, please suggest a better way (if any) to execute this function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.mark_enrollment_completed(IN enrollment_id text)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
    total_contents INTEGER;
    completed_content_count INTEGER;
    user_id TEXT;
    course_id TEXT;
    was_marked BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    SELECT user_id, course_id INTO user_id, course_id FROM enrollments WHERE enrollment_id = enrollment_id;
    SELECT count(*) INTO total_contents FROM course_contents WHERE course_id = course_id;
    SELECT count(*) INTO completed_content_count FROM completed_contents WHERE user_id = user_id;
    IF total_contents = completed_content_count THEN
        UPDATE enrollments SET is_completed = true WHERE enrollment_id = enrollment_id;
        SET was_marked = true;
    ELSE
        SET was_marked = false;
    RETURN was_marked;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 22: END;
            ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 750
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) assignment is done using `:=` operator - there is no SET in PL/pgSQL.

You are also missing the [END IF](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS)

```
IF total_contents = completed_content_count THEN
    UPDATE enrollments SET is_completed = true WHERE enrollment_id = enrollment_id;
    was_marked := true;
ELSE
    was_marked := false;
END IF;
RETURN was_marked;
```